# Awarded a bounty on another person's question but can't comment on answer

Tags: feature-request

I just awarded a bounty that I had placed on another person's question, but since the bounty I had placed drew my reputation to below 50, I don't have the 'comment everywhere' privilege.

Now I would like to give a comment to the answer I awarded, as to give feedback to what I liked about it, and vocalize my appreciation, but I can't. I think that people who awards a bounty should be granted permission to comment on the answers they award.

I know that my case is probably a bit special, as I suspect there are few people who would bounty away their 'comment everywhere' privilege in the first place, and especially not on a question that is not their own, but I still think this would be a nice feature to have.

The answer I awarded is one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843034/dagger-2-does-not-generate-component).

Comment: I agree that the bounty giver should be able to add comments, but even the comment dialog itself says that you shouldn't add "thank you" comments.

Comment: Ok, just got an upvote for one of my answers, so I will now be able to make a comment after all, but I still think this is a potentially missing feature..

Comment: @zondo at the time being I was not able to see the dialog, so I didn't really know. I was however in this instance not intending to say a generic thanks, but to be specific about how I found that particular answer more helpful than other tips I've seen. I believe that can be helpful to other users who may read the answer as well. But, yes, I will take care not to write generic thank you comments :)

Comment: Cross-site dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192403/comment-on-posts-that-you-have-an-open-bounty-on-despite-reputation